# Light colorscheme issue causing black background when scrolling down using J

Tags: colorscheme

```
colorscheme leya
set background=light
```

whole `.vimrc` 
https://gist.github.com/francium/e29aa1600abd158fe08b34218e1f3bd6

Only happens when you scroll down using `j`

Tried it with another light theme, wikipedia -- Same issue

Leya -- https://github.com/marlun/vim-starwars

Wikipedia -- https://github.com/mtglsk/wikipedia.vim

EDIT:

1. Just tried without any .vimrc, same result.
2. Toggling NERDTree fixes the issue

[image]

Comment: can you try adding `set t_ut=` in your vimrc?

Comment: @nobe4 Yes, that fixed it. Can you post it as an actual answer (if you want the points)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following configuration fixed OP's issue:

```
set t_ut=
```

This says to Vim to use the current background's color to clear the screen.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15095377/2558252