# Vim with non-default background on Ubuntu shows purple color for non-text space after scrolling the screen

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I'm at a loss at how to get rid of this jarring purple background surrounding any text that isn't visible when vim initially loads the file and displays the text.  It appears when I scroll past the initially displayed text, but not when I jump to an entirely different area or resize the window.  This happens for all file types I've tried so far.[image]

I've even replaced my `.vimrc` file with this extremely minimal version, and the issue still occurs (I used this `.vimrc` file for the above screenshot)

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required
highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=darkblue
```

Comment: Since this is happening with such a minimal `.vimrc` file, I'm guessing there might be something wrong with my vim installation, but that would be bizarre, since I just reinstalled Ubuntu about a week ago

Comment: Did you try following the instructions  in the solarized colorscheme readme?  (https://github.com/altercation/ethanschoonover.com/blob/master/projects/solarized/vim-colors-solarized/README.mkd)

Comment: Nope because this issue is now occurring even without using the solarized theme :/

Comment: Does this http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10742/1821 help ?

Comment: @nobe4 See my previous comment (I'm just trying to make sure you get notified)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following configuration fixed OP's issue:

```
set t_ut=
```

This says to Vim to use the current background's color to clear the screen.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15095377/2558252

Answer (score -1):

You need to add to your .vimrc file `set t_Co=256` that allow the terminal to use colors solarized.

Comment: That didn't have any effect :(